# Implementing MutationObserver in place of DOMSubtreeModified

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, mutation-observers

I have a `select[multiple]` which I have given a class `custom-multiselect` on my page for which I am catching the `DOMSubtreeModified` event as follows:

HTML:

```
<select class="custom-multiselect"></select>
```

JQuery:

```
$('.custom-multiselect').each(function (i, select) {
    var sel = this;
    adjustHeight(sel); //Custom function
    //Binding DOMSubtreeModified to catch if the select list gets modified by the user
    $(sel).on('DOMSubtreeModified', function () {            
        adjustHeight(sel);
    });
    //For Internet Explorer
    $(sel).on('propertychange', function () {
        adjustHeight(sel);
    });
});
```

This approach works flawlessly. I want to convert the `DOMSubtreeModified` function into `MutationObserver` since `DOMSubtreeModified` is depreciated.

So I did something like this:

```
var observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutation) {
    mutation.forEach(function (m) {
        if (m.type == 'subtree') {
            adjustHeight(this);//Can I use m.target here?
        }
    });
});
observer.observe(document.querySelector('select.custom-multiselect'), {
    subtree: true
});
```

But I end up getting error

> TypeError: The expression cannot be converted to return the specified type.

How can I convert my `DOMSubtreeModified` event to be observed by the `MutationObserver`?

Comment: `this` in `adjustHeight` will most certainly not be what you want - did you try m.target?

Comment: I did but I am getting the above mentioned error it doesn't let me know if m.target works or not :-S

Comment: OK, read [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver#MutationObserverInit) - **At the very least, childList, attributes, or characterData must be set to true. Otherwise, "An invalid or illegal string was specified" error is thrown** - also there is no mutation `.type == "subtree"` - I'm surprised your code gets as far as you claim - oh, I see, that error is because you haven't set at least one of `childList`, `attributes`, or `characterData` to true ...

Comment: Thanks, I found .type == 'subtree' from another forum thought it worked that's why I tried. At the moment it's not working with MutationObserver it is working with the DOMSubtreeModified function

Comment: you'll want `type == 'childList` and add `childList: true` to the `.observe` options

Comment: @JaromandaX Thank you for your comment about the required attributes. You saved my day!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- Put the code in place of the old DOM event and use your `sel` variable as the observation target;
- Use `childList` option in MutationObserver because `subtree` doesn't specify what to look for;
- There's no need to check the mutations since you subscribe only to one type.

```
$('.custom-multiselect').each(function() {
    var sel = this;
    adjustHeight(sel);

    new MutationObserver(function() {
        adjustHeight(sel);
    }).observe(sel, {childList: true, subtree: true});
});
```

Or, if you like `.bind` for some reason:

```
new MutationObserver(adjustHeight.bind(null, sel))
    .observe(sel, {childList: true, subtree: true});
```