# Alternative for DOMSubtreeModified jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I write an alternative function for `DOMSubtreeModified`?

```js
$('html').bind('DOMNodeInserted DOMNodeRemoved', function(event) {
  var structure = $(event.target).closest(".form--group");
  structure.find(".thevoornaam, .date_of_birth, .stepbirthVal, .livingkid, .right, .limitSelected, .pijlers, .total_pijlers").on("keyup change DOMSubtreeModified", function() {
    if (structure.find(".thevoornaam").val().length > 1 && structure.find(".date_of_birth").val().length > 1 && structure.find('.stepbirthVal').html() == "" && structure.find(".livingkid").is(':checked') && structure.find(".right").is(':checked') && structure.find(".limitSelected:checked").val() == "1" && structure.find(".pijlers").val() != null && structure.find(".total_pijlers").val() != null) {
      $("#stepbirth").removeClass("disabled");
    } else if (structure.find(".thevoornaam").val().length > 1 && structure.find(".date_of_birth").val().length > 1 && structure.find('.stepbirthVal').html() == "" && structure.find(".livingkid").is(':checked') && structure.find(".right").is(':checked') && structure.find(".limitSelected:checked").val() == "0") {
      $("#stepbirth").removeClass("disabled");
    } else {
      $("#stepbirth").addClass("disabled");
    }
  });
});
```

This function is working fine but i am getting this message in browser console.

> [Violation] Added synchronous DOM mutation listener to a  event. Consider using MutationObserver to make the page more responsive.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The warning gives you the details of the best way to do this: a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

Comment: See [Implementing MutationObserver in place of DOMSubtreeModified](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41971140/5578773)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Implementing MutationObserver in place of DOMSubtreeModified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41971140/implementing-mutationobserver-in-place-of-domsubtreemodified)